# Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM reservation
WHERE reservation_id IN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM reservation, guest, guests_transactions, transaction_guest
    WHERE 
        transaction_guest.transaction_id = guests_transactions.transaction_id
        AND guests_transactions.guest_id = guest.guest_id
        AND guest.reservation_id = reservation.reservation_id
        AND transaction_guest.exp_date REGEXP 16
);
```

Comment: You seem to be selecting everything from all of those tables, rather than just the reservation ID for the `IN` part of the query. You may also want to look into table joins or further subqueries.